# How to update solr index by query?

Tags: solr, solrj, hector

I have used solr to update one document successfully. But now I have a core which does not configure the unique key, so how can I update the document by query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to update SolR document without having UniqueKey for your documents. You'll have to drop all documents from core and reload from scratch each time you want to update a document.

More info here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey